# jspdf is not able to capture the div content properly for highcharts to download as pdf format

Tags: html, highcharts, jspdf

I want to download the content of html in the pdf fprmat,but here in my case I am using highcharts but when I download the pdf its not able to capture the content of chart,it can able to capture only text contents.I have used all the extra plugin like addimage,standard font etc even though it not able to print.is there any other plugin I need to use,or do I need to use any highcharts plugin for that,here is the code below

```js
    $(function () {
    
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
     $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.fromHTML(
                $('#container').html(), 15, 15, 
                { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers }, 
                function(){ doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); }
            );
    
        });  
    });
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    
        title: {
            text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
        },
    
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
        },
    
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Employees'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
    
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                label: {
                    connectorAllowed: false
                },
                pointStart: 2010
            }
        },
    
        series: [{
            name: 'Installation',
            data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
        }, {
            name: 'Manufacturing',
            data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales & Distribution',
            data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
        }, {
            name: 'Project Development',
            data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
        }],
    
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.immex1.com/js/jspdf/plugins/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
     <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To download the chart content you can use Highcharts exporting. To export on custom button click [chart.exportChart](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#exportChart) method can be use:

```
$('#cmd').click(function() {
  chart.exportChart({
    type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
  });
});
```

Notice, additionally [exporting module](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js) has to be loaded after highcharts script.

Docs reference: 
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/ue3pav2g/1/

**EDIT:**

To download multiple charts using jspdf you have to follow this steps:

1. send AJAX to Highcharts server with options for each of the charts.
   The return will be an URL to the image on the server.
2. convert images from Highcharts server into base64 format. (You can use this approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/10077925)
3. Add charts images, logo, footer to pdf using jspdf library and save the result.

Code:

```
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    var obj = {
        options: JSON.stringify(chartOptions),
        type: 'image/png',
        async: true
      },
      exportUrl = 'https://export.highcharts.com/',
      imgContainer = $("#container"),
      doc = new jsPDF(),
      chartsLen = 1,
      imgUrl;

    var calls = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < chartsLen; i++) {
      calls.push({
        type: 'post',
        url: exportUrl,
        data: obj,
      });
    }

    $.when(
      $.ajax(calls[0])
    ).done(function(c1) {

      imgUrl = exportUrl + c1;

      toDataURL(imgUrl)
        .then(dataUrl => {
          doc.setFontSize(30);
          doc.text(35, 25, 'First caption');
          doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 15, 40);
          doc.text(35, 175, 'Second caption');
          doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'PNG', 15, 185);
          doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        })
    });
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/4a8u16ck/1/

Comment: I understood what you are saying.. But here my requirement is different  that is there will be multiple chart in one page, I need to download all those content including logo and footer of the page. That's why I am using jspdf.

Comment: I've edited my answer to download multiple charts with additional content using jspdf library.

Comment: Actually I need to capture and download the content of charts in pdf.I have already  done with dynamic ids but chart is always rendering same,its not changing here I have updated the code http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview   Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of the charts you need to convert the HTML part to canvas, download npm package html2canvas.
There is an in built function html2canvas which takes element id as an argument and return the canvas. Returned canvas can be added to document using addImage function.

```
//you need to import html2canvas
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas'
$(function () {

$('#cmd').click(function () {
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   let chartelement = document.getElementById('container');

function tellMeWhenToReturn(){
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  const elementToPrint = document.getElementById(id) //The html element to become a pdf
  html2canvas(elementToPrint).then((canvas) => {
    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    resolve(contentDataURL );
  });
});
}

tellMeWhenToReturn().then((data)=>{
  doc.addImage(data, 'margin', 'widthimage', 'imageheight');
 });


    });  
});
```

Comment: Though its bit late you can try and let me know